# Split variable from comma into multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently displaying a bike's frame color in small boxes as [you can see live here](http://roldskov.sp34k.dk/produkter/cykler/mountain-bikes/specialized/epic-fsr/) if you scroll down and click the small colored boxes.

Some frames have two colors so instead of showing only one color, I'd like the small color boxes to use CSS3 `background-color` and display two colors instead of one IF the frame has two color values, example here:

[image]

**My code looks like this.**

```
@foreach (var bikeColor in images)
  {
    var color = bikeColor.GetPropertyValue("frameColor");

    <div class="frameColor" data-color="#@color" style="background-color:#@color"></div>
   }
```

`frameColor` is a string from Umbraco, inside the string I add the colors like so:`cccccc`. But I'd like to add two colors like this: `cccccc, 000000` and then somehow split the two color values into two variables and display them IF there is two colors.

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
  $(".frameColor").each(function () {
        var categoryImage = $(this).parent("div").next("a").find(".categoryImage");
        categoryImage.first().show();

        if ($(categoryImage).length > 1) {

            $(this).on('click', function () {
                var color = $(this).data('color').replace('#', '');

                $(".frameColor").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");

                $(categoryImage).hide().filter(function () {
                    return $(this).data('frame-color') == color;
                }).show();
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Thank you for the attention

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which splits a string, based on a delimiter you specify and returns an array of the individual parts.

Because you will get an array as a result. You can simply check the `.length` of the array to see how many colors you have and proceed accordingly.

NOTE: Using `.replace()` will also be a good idea so you don't get any unwanted whitespace characters in the individual color values.:

```js
var frameColor = "cccccc, ffffff";

// Strip all the space chars. out of the string and then split 
// where there are commas. Return the result as an array.
var colors = frameColor.replace(/\s+/g, "").split(",");

// Test of the result
console.log("There are " + colors.length + " colors and they are " + colors[0] + " and " + colors[1]);

// Different actions based on # of colors
switch(colors.length){
  case 1:
    console.log("There is only one color");
    break;
  case 2:
    console.log("There are two colors");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Scott, thank you for your reply. How do I parse the array over to my @foreach where the background color is generated?

Comment: `@forEach` is invalid syntax in JavaScript, so I don't know what that is. But, if you declare the `colors` variable in a scope that is accessible to your functions, then wherever you are receiving the string in the first place, you can just assign the `replace/split` code to the variable there.